# Непервообразные предлоги.

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти полный перечень непервообразных предлогов и предложных сочетаний?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непервообразные предлоги – это предлоги, имеющие живые словообразовательные отношения и лексико-семантические связи с знаменательными словами – существительными, наречиями и глаголами (деепричастиями). Непервообразные предлоги гораздо более многочисленны, чем предлоги первообразные. Все они немногозначны, причем каждый такой предлог соединяется только с одним каким-нибудь падежом. Все непервообразные предлоги делятся на предлоги отыменные (ввиду, в качестве, во имя, по линии, под видом), наречные (близ, сверх, после, подле, согласно) и отглагольные (включая, исключая, не считая).

Вряд ли целесообразно все предлоги здесь перечислять, их очень много, да и за полноту списка не поручусь, так как это не закрытая группа слов, процесс перехода существительных, наречий. деепричастий в разряд предлогов продолжается.

Гораздо важнее (чем просто иметь список) уметь отличать предлоги от омонимичных знаменательных слов.

Больший список, чем в "Грамматике", ни в одном учебнике не видела .[здесь](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1645-1668.html#1655-1)

Answer (score 0):

> > > Скажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти полный перечень непервообразных предлогов и предложных сочетаний?

Полный - нигде. Это постоянно пополняемое множество. 
остальное - см. [@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)