# разграничение наречия и предлога

Tags: предлоги, наречия

Почему наречие " втайне от" относят именно к наречиям, а не к производным предлогам?
Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что писал когда-то о *"втайне (от кого-нибудь)"* В.В. Виноградов (http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5310&0a0=13):

> **§ 30. Предложные наречия**
>        Наречие с трудом и в сравнительно редких случаях несет на себе тяжесть управления. Случаев зависимости других слов от наречий
> относительно немного (например: *сказать что-нибудь курам насмех;
> приходиться подстать кому-, чему-нибудь*). Круг наречных
> словосочетаний тесен. Характерно, что деепричастия, распространенные
> зависимыми объектами, обычно отходят далеко от наречий в глубь системы
> глагола. Чаще же всего наречие, если позволяют его лексические
> значения, передает свое управление глаголу, а само выступает лишь в
> роли грамматического выразителя падежного отношения, правда, почти
> всегда с более конкретным лексическим содержанием, чем предлог.
>
> Таким образом, возникает целая серия форм переходного типа от наречия
> к предлогу. Конечно, переход наречия в предлог, степень его сближения
> с предлогом обусловлены лексическим и грамматическим значением
> наречия. Они зависят от смысловой близости наречия к значениям
> предлогов.

И далее:

> Например, ***втайне от кого-нибудь*** не утрачивает своего наречного
> значения, так как оно не соответствует семантике русских предлогов.
> Значение этого слова не только слишком конкретно (ср. тайком, тайно,
> которые тоже могут сочетаться с предлогом от), но и слишком далеко от
> тех грамматических отношений, которые выражаются предлогами.

**P.S.**

**"Подстать"** выше слитно — не опечатка. Это слово когда-то писалось раздельно,  у Даля и в словаре Ушакова приводилось в слитном написании, потом опять вернулось к раздельному...

Comment: простите, а как вы понимаете этот текст? Что именно Виноградов признает здесь наречием: ***"втайне", "втайне от", "в тайне от кого-нибудь"***?!  По мне так "втайне" - наречие, о нем и говорит Виноградов. Но в отношении "втайне от" Виноградов таких заявлений не делает. И уж тем более не пришло бы ему в голову объявлять наречием всю выжеленную у вас конструкцию "втайне от кого-нибудь".

Comment: Конечно, наречием у Виноградова признаётся только ***втайне***. Ни *втайне от*, ни *втайне от кого-нибудь* наречием он не считал. И предлогом тоже не считал. Правильнее было бы, наверное, употребить в этом тексте примерно такие выделения: ***втайне** от кого-нибудь* или такие: *втайне (от кого-нибудь)*. Но, к сожалению, Виноградов так не поступил, а я при его цитировании не счёл себя вправе настолько сильно отступить от авторского текста. Единственное, что я сделал, — авторский курсив выделил полужирным.

Comment: Ясно. спасибо.  А у автора наречие - "втайне от". Отсюда, имхо, все его заморочки.

Answer (score 1):

Трудно сказать почему. По недоразумению, возможно. А кто так относит?

По мне так *"втайне"* - наречие (отвечает на вопрос как?), это подчеркивается слитным написанием.
А вот *"втайне от"* - это уже, вернее всего, именно непервообразный предлог.
Вопрос в другом. Чем этот наречный предлог отличается от отыменного "в тайне от"?!
А если ничем, кроме написания, то зачем он нужен-то?

В одном могу согласиться: путаница здесь на данный момент изрядная даже на академическом уровне. Систематика и критерии отнесения еще ждут своих четких формулировок.
[Непервообразные предлоги.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6440)